# Perform DELETE operation to provide sync facility between android devices

Tags: android, sql, synchronization

I want to provide a sync facility in my android app. I am using sql database and have web services running. I already have written back-end code to perform `CRUD` operations. All the code is working fine so this is more of an information oriented question .

Currently I'm able to exchange new/updated data on different devices but having problem with `DELETE` operation. If I delete any entry from db it removes that entry on the device and from server db as well but not sure how to delete same entry on the other devices as well.
Suppose I'm using 2 devices, Now I have 2 solutions in mind whenever a user try to sync with server -

1. Send deviceA local data to update server, Delete all local data and get new data(may have new data from deviceB) from server and save it on deviceA
2. While performing `DELETE` from deviceA, save those `DELETE` queries in a new table on server and while performing sync on deviceB, make those queries on deviceB. Of course if entry is already deleted sqlite query in android will just return -1 so that is not an issue.

I think option 2 is better since I will be doing less operations but I am new to back-end programming and have no prior experience or knowledge and might be far away from the best practices regarding syncing. Please suggest how should I tackle this problem.

Comment: There's an old joke in CS-  "there's only two hard problems in Computer Science- naming things and cache coherency".  This is cache coherency.  Fixing this is non-trivial, I doubt you've even started thinking about the corner cases.  You may want to look at distributed databases like firebase, couchbase, etc instead.

Comment: I think it really depends on your business requirement. For different requirement, the approach would be different. Do you really need real-time synchronization ? full app data synchronization (vs single page data sync) ?    And BTW, if you can sync new/update data, it would be quite easy to implement delete data, put a extra deleted flag to your data and you convert your 'delete data' to 'update data' sync. And find another way  to delete those flagged data.

Comment: @YuanZ There is a Grocery list option in app which should be in-sync on 2 devices. Suppose someone on deviceA thinks that any particular item will not be required and deletes it, it should be reflected on deviceB so that other person doesn't mistakenly buy it.

Comment: @Ranjan, just put extra DELETED flag for all item, and go with the existing update approach. In your UI side, filter out all DELETED = true items. Would this solve your problem ?

Comment: @YuanZ Yes, that might work as well. Thanks, I'll give it a try.